# Which is more efficient - Function call multiple times or setting variable?

Tags: swift4

In Swift 4 which is a more efficient way: Making a function call once and storing the return in a variable (or let) then using that variable multiple times OR making the function call multiple times?

For example using this function (or something equally simple):

```
func myMeth()->String{
    return "this string"
}
```

Then:

```
let myVar = myMeth()
var1 = myVar
var2 = myVar
var3 = myVar
var4 = myVar
```

OR:

```
var1 = myMeth()
var2 = myMeth()
var3 = myMeth()
var4 = myMeth()
```

Comment: In general in any language a function call will have overhead that merely copying a value will not, though a good compiler may help to make up for it somewhat.

Comment: @matt  So assuming my actual method is as simple as my example (like a set/get property) it shouldn't matter unless the function calls are extremely numerous - like hundreds or thousands as opposed to 10's ?

Comment: Only real way to know: measure. That’s what Instruments is for.

Comment: @matt True....I think the measured values I'm dealing with are so small it may not matter and may just be a coding style preference.

Comment: Why not use the get and set blocks instead?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would say store the return value in a variable but that depends on whether what the function will return will change later on. For your example use a variable as running a function will have more overhead especially if it is a complicated one.

Comment: My method is used like a set/get property, so typically the retrieved value does not change during the time a View is displayed, but may change before the next time the View is shown. So I could 'get' it when the viewwillappear for example.

Comment: Every time that the result will have changed re-execute the function to update the variable or create a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function and store result in a variable both are different things. It depends what you need.

1. Calling a function is better when you don't want to store a value in a variable. You just want to access the value wherever you need.
2. Store in a variable, use it when you want to persist the result globally within that viewController.

If you store the result in a variable, it will always consume memory until your ViewController is in memory but calling a function will take processing memory only when you will call it.